# Drush is not recognizing Acquia extension

Tags: drush

I am using Acquia and Drush 8.1.8. I am following Acquia's instructions to load Drush extensions and aliases. My `~/.drush` directory looks like this:

```
nickheiner@Nicks-MacBook-Pro.local:~/.drush  λ ls -l ~/.drush/
total 176
-rw-------@ 1 nickheiner  staff  43320 Feb  9 13:25 acapi.drush.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 nickheiner  staff    204 Feb  9 13:26 cache
-rw-------@ 1 nickheiner  staff   6026 Feb  9 13:14 cloudapi.acquia.com.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 nickheiner  staff   7741 Dec 19 16:52 drush.bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 nickheiner  staff   1937 Dec 19 16:52 drush.complete.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 nickheiner  staff   2811 Dec 19 16:52 drush.prompt.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 nickheiner  staff  13628 Feb  9 13:19 drushrc.php
-rw-------@ 1 nickheiner  staff   1416 Feb  9 13:14 preview1.aliases.drushrc.php
```

However, Drush is not recognizing the commands:

```
λ ./drush cache-clear drush
'drush' cache was cleared.                                                [success]

λ ./drush help --filter=acapi
The specified command category acapi does not exist.                      [error]
```

I am also not seeing the alias:

```
λ ./drush sa
@none
@self
default
```

I tried opening up the permissions so they look like the following, but it did not solve the problem:

```
λ ls -la ~/.drush
total 176
drwxrwxrwx  10 nickheiner  staff    340 Feb 10 10:36 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 57 nickheiner  staff   1938 Feb 10 11:04 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 nickheiner  staff  43320 Feb  9 13:12 acapi.drush.inc
drwxrwxrwx   6 nickheiner  staff    204 Feb  9 13:26 cache
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 nickheiner  staff   6026 Feb  9 13:12 cloudapi.acquia.com.pem
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nickheiner  staff   7741 Dec 19 16:52 drush.bashrc
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nickheiner  staff   1937 Dec 19 16:52 drush.complete.sh
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nickheiner  staff   2811 Dec 19 16:52 drush.prompt.sh
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nickheiner  staff  13628 Feb  9 13:19 drushrc.php
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 nickheiner  staff   1416 Feb  9 13:12 preview1.aliases.drushrc.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run `drush cc drush`?

Comment: Yes, I have run that command.

Comment: I suggest adding a link to "Acquia's instructions to load Drush extensions" so you can get help from everyone that uses Drush. I also recommend running ```drush status``` to see where Drush expects it's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you can see your acquia site aliases?

```
drush sa
```

I haven't done anything beyond the suggested `tar -C $HOME -xf $HOME/Downloads/acquiacloud.tar.gz` and `drush help --filter=acapi` shows all the commands.

Comment: I am not able to see the site aliases.

Comment: I think thats your problem. Would highly recommend you go through the steps here again: https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/drush-aliases

Re download your aliases, extract them:

    `tar -C $HOME -xf $HOME/Downloads/mysite.tar.gz`

Then try `drush sa` again